# Cheapest way to use AWS for simple response

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

What I wanted to achieve is pretty simple, if you send a request to some address, the response you get is a single integer number, like 13 for example. I think it is equivalent to hosting a .html page with single number on that page and then I can parse that string in my application. (It is a Unity game, using the WWW class to send the request.)

(This is actually a version number. If it is greater than what I stored in my app I would update it and then send another request to other place and retrieve something bigger)

I am looking for the cheapest way that can handle this. I planned to use AWS but confused what component should be use? S3? EC2? Lambda? CloudFront?

If you think doing this on a web hosting or Heroku or something else is better, I also wanted to hear about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serve up a simple value, S3 should do the trick.

Create a bucket in the console, using lonely lowercase letters, digits, and dashes in the name. The name has to be globally unique among all of S3, so make up something unique.  We'll call the bucket name `example-bucket`.

Create your file on your computer with the desired contents.  If plain text, call it `version.txt`.

In the AWS console, select the bucket, and upload the file.  While clicking through the "next" screens, put a check next to "make everything public" and accept the defaults.  Upload the file.

Now, go to https://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/version.txt in your browser and verify (using your actual bucket name.  That's your download link.

Done.  As long as you don't expect to handle over about 800 requests *per second*, this will do exactly what you want.

Review the S3 pricing, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Although  this question is suitable for Server Fault,
EC2 using nginx or apache web server will be sufficient.

Put Load balancer in front of EC2 instances.